# All chrome popups display with transparency bug in chrome in a VM

Tags: google-chrome, virtual-machine, hardware-acceleration

I spend a lot of time using virtual machines, and a lot of that time using Chrome.

All of the browser dialogs, such as those for extensions, but also things such as chrome prompting certain things etc render with a transparency bug.

The bug can be fixed by either not using it within a virtual machine, or turning OFF hardware accelleration in chrome settings.

Thing is, neither of these are suitable for me.

It's quite frustrating, and has been happening for around 8 months or so now.

I know of other people facing the same issue in the same scenario, and between us we are all using different hardware and different virtual machine software. Personally, I am using VMWare Workstation 14 though.

Any known work around / fix etc would be super useful.

Here is an example of clicking the lock icon in address bar on Google.
[image]

Comment: Does this happen in other programs? or in VirtualBox?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Just chrome, no other programs have issues.
I get this in VMware Workstation 14, but know others who also get it in esxi and other virtualisation software

Answer (score 11):

I fixed this in Chrome going to:
**chrome://flags**
search for:
Choose ANGLE graphics backend 
Change from **Default** to **OpenGL**

Comment: Thanks, that also fixes a transparency issue with keepassxc-browser extension, no need to turn off 3D acceleration in vm settings.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=929764) the issue is an active bug with Chrome (chromium) in VMware SVGA. Disabling GPU acceleration is the only fix for now. I recommend you to keep checking the thread for any developments in future.

Answer (score 0):

Some measures that can help this kind of problem:

1. In VM *Settings > Display*, uncheck "Accelerate 3D Graphics".
2. To use the OpenGL renderer instead of DX11, in the `.vmx` file add the lines

   ```
   mks.enableGLRenderer = "TRUE"
   mks.enableDX11Renderer = "FALSE"
   ```

Answer (score -2):

For any macOS users out there, I was running into a similar bug, but it turns out I just needed to turn off hardware acceleration.

Comment: What does this answer add that other answers didn't already say?